# Using $set with an index variable to update a document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

> For the document matching the criteria _id equal to 100, the following
>   operation update the value second element (array index of 1) in the
>   tags field and the rating field in the first element (array index of
>   0) of the ratings array.

```
db.products.update(
   { _id: 100 },
   { $set:
      {
        "tags.1": "rain gear",
        "ratings.0.rating": 2
      }
   }
)
```

The above is a quote from the [mongodb $set documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/), how would I go about adding a variable for the index so instead of `"tags.1"` it becomes `"tags."+index`

For example, if `index` is equal to 7 it would return the equivalent of `"tags.7"`.

This is my code:

```
Users.findOneAndUpdate({'username': post.username}, { 
  $set: {
    "notifications.0": { 
      'id': post._id,  'message': post.message,  'amount': amount 
    } 
  } 
}, function () {})
```

It works perfectly but only because I hardcoded the `0` as the index. I want to replace that hardcoded `0` with an `index` variable.

Comment: What's wrong with replacing `"notifications.0"` with `"notifications."+index` ?

Comment: syntax error @Aaron

Comment: thanks @JohnyHK that question led me to my answer! since i dont think its an exact dupe ill post my answer.

Comment: maybe it is a dupe :/ should i delete it?

Comment: It's the same basic issue so I did mark it as a dupe. No need to delete though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build up the query like so

```
var key = "notifications."+index;
var obj = {};
obj[key] = { 'id': post._id, 'message': post.message, 'amount': amount };
Users.findOneAndUpdate({'username': post.username}, { $set: obj }, function () {}
```